# npm private module not finding module

Tags: node.js, npm

I have just started using npm private modules, and cannot pick up the module in my code.

The module is up and running on npmjs, I can install it correctly, but my require statement is failing.

My username has a dot in it.

I'm running os-x.

So the module is `@user.name/my-module-name`.

I am doing an `npm i --save @user.name/my-module-name`, which is setting the package.json correctly, with current versions and so on, and pulling the module into my ./node_modules dir.

**Error here:**
When I do the `require('@user.name/my-module-name')` however, I'm getting a `Cannot find module` error.

I have tried escaping parts of the name, and addressing it directly, to no avail. This feels like a node problem.

How can I pick up the module from code?

Comment: You have stated a lot of facts that im sure are causing frustration -- however it would help if you had an actual question :-)

Comment: Thanks for that!! I was trying to be factual, and show what I had tried, and missed the whole point of asking a question!!

Comment: What happens if you have `@user.name/my-module-name` in the package.json but `require('my-module-name')` in the actual code?

Comment: Same thing. ```Module not found```. The module is in ```./node_modules/@user.name/my-module-name``` which is where it should be, I think.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages) I would think that it is a bug, and that dots in user names is not supported -- do you have a opportunity to create a different account without a dot in the username and use that account as a collaborator to make a workaround?

Comment: Hi. Yeah, that sounds close. I'll see if I can do that. I looked in the ```node``` code to find related tests, but it was going to be a mammoth task. I'll see about creating a separate scope, and maybe see about raising a bug.

Comment: If you do solve, then please post an answer to you own question -- I'm sure you will not be the last person with this problem

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, set the package.json::main property to the relevant file:

`"main": "./src/largestHref.js"`

It was finding the module, but not the code...